# Indefinite integral: $\int \frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt x(1+\sqrt[3]x)}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I need :

> $$ \int \frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{x}(1+\sqrt[3]{x})}$$

Can you give me a hint, which way would suit best? I tried substitution, but don't have an idea what to substitute.. :/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

HINT:

As the [Integrand](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Integrand.html) involves $\displaystyle \sqrt x=x^{\frac12},\sqrt[3]x=x^{\frac13}$

and $\displaystyle\mathrm{gcd}\left(\frac12,\frac13\right)=\frac1{\mathrm{lcm}(2,3)}=\frac16$

put  $\displaystyle y=x^{\frac16}\implies \sqrt x=y^3,\sqrt[3]x=y^2$ and $\displaystyle x=y^6$

Answer (score 2):

$$
\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt x\left(1+\sqrt[3]{x}\right)}=\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt[6]x^{3}\left(1+\sqrt[6]{x^2}\right)}=|\sqrt[6]{x}=t\Rightarrow x=t^6\Rightarrow dx=6t^5dt|
$$
$$
=\int\frac{6t^5dt}{t^3\left(1+t^2\right)}=6\int\frac{t^2dt}{1+t^2}=6\int\frac{t^2+1-1}{1+t^2}dt=6\int\left(1-\frac{1}{1+t^2}\right)dt
$$
$$
=6\int dt-6\int \frac{1}{1+t^2}dt=6t-6\arctan t=6(\sqrt[6]{x}-\arctan \sqrt[6]{x})+C
$$