# What method should I use when integrating this problem?

Tags: calculus, integration

What method should I use when integrating this problem? $$\int \frac{dx}{x^{\frac12}+x^{\frac13}}$$

Comment: Sami Ben Romdhane has already answered it, after you have to do polynomdivision and get $6\int\frac{t^3}{t+1}=6\int t^2-t+\frac{t}{t+1}=6\int t^2-t+(1-\frac{1}{t+1})$. Now you should be able to do the rest.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/529961/indefinite-integral-int-frac-mathrm-dx-sqrt-x1-sqrt3x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $t=x^{1/6}$ then $dx=6t^5dt$ and the the integral becomes
$$6\int\frac{t^3dt}{t+1}$$
Can you take it from here?