# How to Find the Limit at a Point?

Tags: calculus, limits

How do you find: $$\mathrm{\lim_{x\ \to \ 64} = \frac{x^{\frac{1}{3}}-4}{x^{\frac{1}{2}} -8}}$$
I was thinking that you might have to use the pinching theorem, but I can't find a suitable inequality to get the answer. Can someone please give a hint to get me started on this question.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As lcm$(3,2)=6$  choose $x=y^6$

$$\mathrm{\lim_{x\ \to \ 64} = \frac{x^{\frac{1}{3}}-4}{x^{\frac{1}{2}} -8}}\implies\lim_{y\to2}\dfrac{y^2-2^2}{y^3-2^3}=?$$

Now $(a^n-b^n)=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\cdots +ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})$

As $y\to2,y\ne 2\iff y-2\ne0$ so can be cancelled safely from the numerator & the denominator

Comment: See also : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/529961/indefinite-integral-int-frac-mathrm-dx-sqrt-x1-sqrt3x

Answer (score 2):

Using L'Hopital Rule gives 
$$\mathrm{\lim_{x\ \to \ 64} = \frac{x^{\frac{1}{3}}-4}{x^{\frac{1}{2}} -8}}=\frac{\frac13x^{-2/3}}{\frac12x^{-1/2}}=\frac13$$