# Solve this indefinite integral : $\int\frac{dx}{(x^{1/3} - 1)\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

How to solve this indefinite integral?

$$\int\frac{dx}{(x^{1/3} - 1)\sqrt{x}}$$

Comment: Try substituting $u=x^{1/6}$

Comment: @JohnDoe That could almost be an answer.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/529961/indefinite-integral-int-frac-mathrm-dx-sqrt-x1-sqrt3x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=u^6$. Then, $dx=6u^5du$.

The integral then becomes
$$I=\int\frac{dx}{(x^{\frac13}-1)\sqrt{x}}dx=\int\frac{6u^5du}{(u^2-1)u^3}$$

$$I=\int\frac{6u^5du}{u^5-u^3}=\int\left(6+\frac{6}{u^2-1}\right)du$$

Express $$\frac{6}{u^2-1}=\frac{A}{u+1}+\frac{B}{u-1}$$

and solve using the method of partial fractions.

Comment: In your last step, one should of course just cancel $u^3$ first to get $6/(u^2-1)$.

Comment: @mickep Sorry, I had missed that. Thank you

Comment: @GoodDeeds Could you explain how to solve such questions generally. How did you deduce what substitution to make here?  ps. thanks for the good deed :p

Comment: @AdityaMehta You choose the substitution which will get rid of all the unpleasant radicals ($\sqrt\cdot$ and $\sqrt[3]\cdot$ in this case). So we chose $x=u^6$ because $\sqrt{u^6}=u^3$ and $\sqrt[3]{u^6}=u^2$, which are both integer powers, which are easier to work with and integrate. $6$ is convenient here since it is the _lowest common multiple_ of $2$ and $3$, which we got from the two radical's you have ($1/2$ and $1/3$). $x=u^{12}$ or $x=u^{600}$ would also work just as well, $6$ is just the smallest number which works.