# Can you give me hint on how to evaluate $\int \frac{1}{4x^{1/2} + x^{3/2} } dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to evaluate the following integral
$$\int \frac{1}{4x^{1/2} + x^{3/2} } dx$$
I tried using substitution but that didn't help. I just want a hint. Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/529961/indefinite-integral-int-frac-mathrm-dx-sqrt-x1-sqrt3x/529964#529964

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$x=t^2$$

$$dx=2tdt$$

$$\int \frac{1}{4x^{1/2} + x^{3/2} } dx=  \int \frac{2tdt}{4t+t^3} =\int \frac{2dt}{4+t^2}   $$

That is a well known integral.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Substitute $$x=t^2$$ in your integral

Comment: I see now!!! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Rewrite your integral as:

$$ \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}( 4 + x)} dx $$

Now can you solve it using **substitution**! What substitution do you think is the best in this case?

Comment: Yes! If I pick $u = \sqrt{x}$ then I will get a very nice form of $\int \frac{1}{4+u^2} $ which can be solve using $\arctan$. Thank you.

Comment: Don't forget the 2 in-front of the $\int \frac{1}{4+u^2}$ since the derivative of $\sqrt{x} = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x} }$