# Help with algebra in evaluating a limit

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

Good evening folks. I'm doing some self-study from the eighth edition of Stewart Calculus (metric version), and I ran into this problem on page 103:

Evalute $$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{x^{1/3} - 1}{x^{1/2}- 1}$$

Now, I understand that the general strategy here is to use a substitution, and I've done so; the problem is that I don't get anything familiar/factorable. I've tried setting $h = x^{1/3} - 1$, $h = x^{1/2} - 1$, $h = x^{1/3}$,$ h = x^{1/2}$, but I'm not getting anywhere with it.

This is really doing my head in, as I feel that I should be able to handle this sort of problem without trouble. As such, if you kind people could go through the working of it, that'd be a HUGE help. Cheers!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/529961/indefinite-integral-int-frac-mathrm-dx-sqrt-x1-sqrt3x/529964#529964

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Substitute $$x=t^6$$ in your limit.

Comment: If x = t^6, then x^1/3 - 1 = t^2 - 1 and x^1/2 - 1 = t^3 - 1, and as x approaches 1 so does t. The numerator can be factored as (t + 1)(t - 1)/(t - 1)(t^2 + t + 1), which of course reduces to (t + 1)/(t^2 + t + 1). The limit as t approaches 1 is 2/3.

Comment: My question to you is: how did you know, or guess, that x should be t^6?

Comment: Going by the link submitted by another answerer, it seems that it comes down to finding the LCM of the powers of x, is that right?

Comment: @MarcusHendriksen Yes. Substituting $x\mapsto t^6$ essentially “gets rid of” the fractional powers in the numerator and denominator since $6=\mathrm{lcm}(3,2)$.

Comment: This have i done with the substitution above!

Answer (score 1):

Use this general method:

$$(x-1)=(x^{\frac13}-1)(x^{\frac23}+x^{\frac13}+1)$$
and
$$(x-1)=(x^{\frac12}-1)(x^{\frac12}+1)$$

so 
$$\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x^{\frac13}-1}{x^{\frac12}-1}=\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{\frac{x-1}{x^{\frac23}+x^{\frac13}+1}}{\frac{x-1}{x^{\frac12}+1}}=\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x^{\frac12}+1}{x^{\frac23}+x^{\frac13}+1}=\frac23$$