# A solution for the integral $\int \frac{\sqrt[3]{x} }{\sqrt[3]{x^2} -\sqrt{x} } dx $ and WA's "invalid input".

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, closed-form, wolfram-alpha

> **Problem:**
>
> $$\displaystyle \int \frac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{\sqrt[3]{x^2} -\sqrt{x} } dx$$

My attempts:

$$\displaystyle \int \frac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{\sqrt[3]{x^2} -\sqrt{x} } dx={\displaystyle\int} \dfrac{1}{6x^\frac{5}{6}}\cdot \dfrac{6x^\frac{2}{3}}{\sqrt[6]{x}-1}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Substitute $u=\sqrt[6]{x} \longrightarrow \dfrac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x} = \dfrac{1}{6x^\frac{5}{6}} \longrightarrow \mathrm{d}x=6x^\frac{5}{6}\,\mathrm{d}u$, we have

$$\sqrt{x}=u^3$$

$$x^\frac{2}{3}=u^4$$

$$x^\frac{7}{6}=u^7$$

$$=\displaystyle\int \dfrac{u^4}{u-1}\,\mathrm{d}u$$

Now, let's solving

$${\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{u^4}{u-1}\,\mathrm{d}u$$

Substitute $v=u-1 \longrightarrow \dfrac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}u} = 1 \longrightarrow \mathrm{d}u=\mathrm{d}v$, we have

$$u^4=\left(v+1\right)^4$$

$$={\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{\left(v+1\right)^4}{v}\,\mathrm{d}v={\displaystyle\int}\left(v^3+4v^2+6v+\dfrac{1}{v}+4\right)\mathrm{d}v={\displaystyle\int}v^3\,\mathrm{d}v+4{\displaystyle\int}v^2\,\mathrm{d}v+6{\displaystyle\int}v\,\mathrm{d}v+{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{v}\,\mathrm{d}v+4{\displaystyle\int}1\,\mathrm{d}v=\ln\left(|v|\right)+\dfrac{v^4}{4}+\dfrac{4v^3}{3}+3v^2+4v=4\left(u-1\right)+\dfrac{\left(u-1\right)^4}{4}+\dfrac{4\left(u-1\right)^3}{3}+3\left(u-1\right)^2+\ln\left(|u-1|\right)$$

Keeping all this in mind, we get

> $$\displaystyle \int \frac{\sqrt[3]{x}  }{\sqrt[3]{x^2} -\sqrt{x} } dx=\displaystyle\int\dfrac{u^4}{u-1}\,\mathrm{d}u =24\left(u-1\right)+\dfrac{3\left(u-1\right)^4}{2}+8\left(u-1\right)^3+18\left(u-1\right)^2+6\ln\left(|u-1|\right)+C=24\left(\sqrt[6]{x}-1\right)+\dfrac{3\left(\sqrt[6]{x}-1\right)^4}{2}+8\left(\sqrt[6]{x}-1\right)^3+18\left(\sqrt[6]{x}-1\right)^2+6\ln\left(\left|\sqrt[6]{x}-1\right|\right)+C=\dfrac{3x^\frac{2}{3}}{2}+2\sqrt{x}+3\sqrt[3]{x}+6\left(\sqrt[6]{x}+\ln\left(\left|\sqrt[6]{x}-1\right|\right)\right)+C=6\left(\dfrac{3x^\frac{2}{3}+4\sqrt{x}+6\sqrt[3]{x}+12\sqrt[6]{x}}{12}+\ln\left(\left|\sqrt[6]{x}-1\right|\right)\right)+C$$

I tried to solve this question in [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%E2%88%AB%28x%5E%281%2F3%29%2F%28%28x%5E2%29%5E%281%2F3%29-x%5E%281%2F2%29%29%29%20dx) before sending it here.

Wolfram Alpha gave me :

[image]

Because, before I solved the integral myself, I had to find out if my answer contained elementary functions or not. This is because I learn integrals that can only be solved with basic functions. I only know the "name" of special functions. Then I realized it was an "input error." But unfortunately it wasn't my fault. I didn't write an entry using the math syntax. But my inputs work perfectly even with integrals that cannot be solved by elementary functions. Here are some examples:

[$$\displaystyle \int \sin(x^2)dx$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%E2%88%ABsin%20%28x%5E2%29%20dx)

An integral containing generalized hypergeometric function, error and imaginary error functions: [$$\displaystyle \int \sin(x^2) \log(x)dx$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%E2%88%ABsin%20%28x%5E2%29%20ln%28x%29%20dx)

I can give more complicated integrals, which works my standart input. I reported the situation to Wolfram Alpha. They acknowledged that this was "their fault." And they said they'd fix it as soon as possible.
The reason I wrote this is because of some humiliating sarcasm that some high reputation users do to me. Maybe I was supposed to write this error in another category. I got some roughly comments for the question. I had to show  that it wasn't my "invalid input" . Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't see why you shouldn't manage to compute routinely an antiderivative of $\frac{x^{1/3}}{x^{2/3}-x^{1/2}}$ via the substitution $t=x^{1/6}$

Comment: @Gae.S. Because there is not solution with elementary functions.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/529961/indefinite-integral-int-frac-mathrm-dx-sqrt-x1-sqrt3x

Comment: @labbhattacharjee But, WA says there is not solution

Comment: Wolframalpha is not perfect.

Comment: WA does give the solution. Stop blaming it. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%5E%281%2F3%29+%2F+%28x%5E%282%2F3%29-x%5E%281%2F2%29%29

Comment: @YvesDaoust LOL.

Comment: @YvesDaoust https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%E2%88%ABx%5E%281%2F3%29%2F%28%28x%5E2%29%5E%281%2F3%29-x%5E%281%2F2%29%29

Comment: @Elementary: WA doesn't like the ∫ character in your input.

Comment: @YvesDaoust  But It's an error. Need to send feedback.

Comment: Congrats, you are hiding the fact that the wrong WA answer is due to your invalid formula input !

Comment: @YvesDaoust No need for sarcasm. I know Mathematica syntax. You don't understand me. This works with other integral problems. I just saw it didn't work for the first time. This input is not in vain. It is only the error that needs to be corrected. Because it works very well in other integrals.

Comment: My sarcasm is deserved. You removed the information about your input, which is essential to the understanding of the "problem".

Comment: @YvesDaoust Well, I always respect respectable people and teachers. Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 4):

$$ \int \frac{\sqrt[3]{x}  }{\sqrt[3]{x^2} -\sqrt{x} } dx
= 6\int \frac{\sqrt[3]{t^6}  }{\sqrt[3]{t^{12}} -\sqrt{t^6} }t^5\,dt
= 6\int \frac{t^4}{t-1}\,dt= 6\int\left(\frac{t^4-1}{t-1}+\frac{1}{t-1}\right)\,dt.$$

How could this have no closed-form expression ?